# Cannot call method indexOf undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, indexof

I'm getting the error, cannotcall method indexOf 'undefined' when using the ko utils array Filter . . .

View Model:

```
viewModel.People = ko.mapping.fromJS(people);


self.Filter1 = ko.observable();    



self.FilteredSystem = ko.computed(function () {

    var Filter1 = self.Filter1();


        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.People(), function (People) {

            return ((People.Name.indexOf(Filter1) !== -1));

        });


}, self);
```

Comment: apparently the `Name` property of `People` is undefined.

Comment: You need to perform basic debugging before asking a question. Have you logged the values you're dealing with to see why they're not what you expect?

Comment: ...and you don't need to wrap the return value in a set of parenthese, much less two sets.

Comment: Please stop opening new questions and spamming the site.

Answer (score -1):

Because you used the mapping plugin, the `Name` property is going to be an observable and you have to unwrap it (`People.Name().indexOf...`) to get its value.